# Area 51 shows incorrect time of private beta start

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, area-51, private-beta

[According to Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80441/vi-and-vim), Vi and Vim launched as private beta at 19:00:00 UTC on 2015-02-03.

However, [the first question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-can-i-add-line-numbers-to-vim) on the site was posted at 16:40:26 UTC on 2015-02-03.

So, the timestamp is incorrect: a bug.

If changing Area 51 code is too much hassle, I suggest fixing the problem from the other end: launch new sites at 19:00:00 UTC. The timing of private beta launch is important for experienced SE users, who would like to create reasonable tags, post good questions, and grab single-digit user Ids. (This is the feature request aspect.)

Comment: *shakes fist, complains about inconsistent launch times and being stuck with userid 88*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Area 51 sets a fixed time largely for historical reasons. Note that it's never actually been accurate - even when sites launched *around* 19:00 UTC, launches are a manual process and are never precise. (Come to think of it, it also doesn't account for daylight savings - launches used to be timed to around 15:00 Eastern, which turns into 19:00 or 20:00 UTC, depending on the time of year.)

These days we try to launch closer to morning Eastern time, but once in a while things get in the way - designers are backlogged and don't get to make the icons, I sleep in another hour, systems are under maintenance, etc. etc. This may even change to another day in the week at some point, who knows.

We *could* have it record the exact time. I don't really know off-hand if that'd break anything that relies on a fixed timestamp. Probably not. But since doing that would not actually fix the core issue of wanting to jump in on a new site early, there isn't much point in digging further into it.

We send out emails when a site goes into private beta. I suggest using that to time your activity.

Last but not least, no site is made or broken by the questions posted or tags created within the first few hours of a private beta. You have *days* to create a great site. Take your time. (But that userid 1 is mine.)

Comment: "Area 51 sets a fixed time largely for historical reasons." - although Area 52 will have this fixed. Right? ;)

Comment: @hichris123 Area 52 is like the next apartment I'm going to rent - a magical place that's going to fix all current problems. ;)

Comment: lel, `integral from 0 to 13 of 4 dx`